# Ajuda com VBA - Excel to TXT

Tags: excel-vba

Tenho uma planilha que uso em minha loja que salva meus pedidos em txt que em outra planilha analiso todos os dados, mas sempre que gero um novo pedido e clico para gerar o TXT ele abre a dialog do Salvar como. tem como pular esta etapa e ele salvar sem abrir o salvar como, especificando o local onde salvar?
esta macro peguei na internet e adaptei para meu uso, mas como sou leigo esta parte não consegui alterar. segue a macro:

```
Sub ExportRangetoFile()
'Update 20130913
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Range("C6:Q20")
Set WorkRng = Range("C6:Q20")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.add
WorkRng.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

ja esta especificado as celulas que ele exporta para o txt, tudo funciona perfeitamente, seria apenas para automatizar mais ainda.

desde ja agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Use isso: saveFile = Application.GetSaveFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt). Eu apenas retirei o "As" "GetSaveAs" e deixei GetSave, testa aí e ver se funciona!

Answer (score 0):

Para não exibir o diálogo salvar como apenas retire a linha `saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")` pois o método `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` é quem exibe o diálogo.

Para especificar o caminho onde salvar o arquivo atribua o caminha para a variável `saveFile`. Nesse exemplo eu usei como caminho `C:\Pedidos.txt`.

```
'Declare uma variável global para servir de incremento para os arquivos
Public arquivo As Integer

Sub ExportRangetoFile()
'Update 20130913
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Range("C6:Q20")
Set WorkRng = Range("C6:Q20")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.add
WorkRng.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Paste

'Comente a próxima linha para não mostrar o dialogo Salvar como
'saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

'Coloque dentro das aspas o caminho do arquivo onde quer salvar o arquivo
'Nesse exemplo usei C:\Pedidos.txt incrementado pela variável arquivo
Let saveFile = "C:\Pedidos" & arquivo & ".txt"

wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close

'incrementa o contador de arquivos para o próximo uso
arquivo = arquivo + 1

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: funcionou em partes, no meu codigo ele gerava sempre um novo arquivo com o nome Pasta1.txt Pasta2.txt sucessivamente, e assim ele subscreve o arquivo Pedidos.txt. preciso que cada vez salve um novo arquivo

Comment: @AndréWillemann: Como é o formato que você utiliza para diferenciar os arquivos?

Comment: dei mais uma pesquisada aqui e consegui, coloquei abaixo a solução.. muito obrigado

Comment: @AndréWillemann Fiz uma modificação veja se lhe ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, ficou assim

```
nomearquivo = Range("T6")
Let saveFile = "C:\Users\André Willemann\Desktop\Relatorios Brecho TUX\" & nomearquivo & ""
```

agora ele salva com o nome da celula T6 que é o numero do pedido

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Exportar_TXT()

 

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  

'Seleciona a guia Extract do Excel depois a célula A1
    Sheets("Extract").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    
    'Iniciar exportação txt via Print com texto exato mostrado em tela sem erro das aspas
    
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    Dim LR As Integer
    Dim LC As Integer
    
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    LR = Worksheets("Extract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = Worksheets("Extract").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Extract " & Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy-hhmmss") & ".txt"
    FileNumber = FreeFile
    
    Open Path For Output As FileNumber
    
    For k = 1 To LR
    
        For i = 1 To LC
            
            If i <> LC Then
                Print #FileNumber, Cells(k, i),
            Else
                Print #FileNumber, Cells(k, i)
            End If
            
        Next i
        
    Next k
    
    Close FileNumber
    

' Caso deseja abrir o notepad imediatamente para conferir o txt gerado só retirar a linha comentada abaixo:

 
    'Shell "notepad.exe " & Path, vbNormalFocus

 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Extract*.txt salvo na pasta onde abriu este Excel!"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).